# Mapping property "role"(foreign key in User table) with the Role Table dotNet Core

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0, razor-pages-crud

I tried to create users by setting roles to them.
The role property is a in the class User as a Required field.
The thing is when I did a  tag to retrieve the data from role table to be able to set the role to the user the insert query doesn't work. The User table have the attribute "roleId" but the User Class have the "role" property from the Role Class.

I will put the Code of the UserCreate Razor Page with the model I used.

UserCreate.cshtml:

```
@page
@model SprintOneBack.UserCreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UserCreate";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>User</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="User.Nom" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="User.Nom" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="User.Nom" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="User.Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="User.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="User.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="User.password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="User.password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="User.password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="User.role" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="User.role" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.displayRoles, "Id", "Label"))">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>-- select Role --</option>
                </select>
                @*<input asp-for="User.role.Label" class="form-control" />*@
                <span asp-validation-for="User.role" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

UserCreateModel.cshtml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SprintOneBack.Model;

namespace SprintOneBack
{
    public class UserCreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public UserCreateModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            displayRoles = _context.Role.ToList();
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Role> displayRoles { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetRoles()
        {
            displayRoles = await _context.Role.ToListAsync();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public User User { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.User.Add(User);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./UserIndex");
        }
    }
}
```

The User Class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Role role { get; set; }
}
```

The Role Class:

```
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

The User Table along with the Role Table:
[image]

Comment: Usually it would be better, if users can have more, than one role... akinda many-to-many-relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an attribute roleId as an Integer and I specified that it is the column roleId in the User table ,and kept the role Attribute (so ef knows that there is a foreign key from Role Table) and regenerated the Tables. And when I regenerated the razor pages I had a nice looking select html tag to list all the roles from the db for each user.

the code looks like this now :

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string password { get; set; }
    [Column("roleId")]
    public int roleId { get; set; }
    public Role role { get; set; }
}
```

CreateUser.cshtml :

```
<h4>User</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="User.Nom" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="User.Nom" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="User.Nom" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="User.Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="User.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="User.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="User.password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="User.password" class="form-control" type="password" />
                <span asp-validation-for="User.password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="User.roleId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="User.roleId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.roleId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "roleId" field is a foreign key automatically generated by ef core. It refers to the key field in the role table.

You can change the code to the following:

UserCreate.cshtml:

```
  <label asp-for="User.role" class="control-label"></label>
  <select asp-for="User.role.Id" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.displayRoles, "Id", "Label"))">
      <option value="" selected disabled>-- select Role --</option>
  </select>
```

UserCreateModel.cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        ModelState.Remove("User.Role.Label");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        Role role = _context.Role.Find(User.role.Id);
        User.role = role;
        _context.User.Add(User);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./UserIndex");
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I just posted the solution that worked for me. Tank you so much for your help.